# Print value of UINavigationController's stack, every time it changes

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to print value of variable in console every time it changes and what is the most convenient way to do it?

EDIT:
I want to track value of UINavigationController's controllers stack

Comment: Look into [_property observers_](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) (`willSet`/ `didSet`).

Comment: @twone if you are interested in UINavigationController please update your question or start a new one

Comment: You could set the delegate and then implement [willShowViewController:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:) to inspect the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For observing the UINavigationController stack, use `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
     // print the stack now.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `didSet` property observer, for example:

```
var exampleValue: String? {
    didSet {
        if let exampleValue = exampleValue {
            print(exampleValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i want to use it with navigation controller's stack how it will look like?

Comment: Consider using an example without the forced unwrapping operator `!` (to avoid introducing bad habits to new Swift users :). E.g., what if we set `exampleValue = nil` in your example above?

Comment: @twone What do you want to do with navigation controller's stack?

Comment: @pableiros I want to see how it's changes when i navigate in my app

Comment: @pableiros Consider using an `if let` or `guard let` instead of an `!= nil`. They both do the same thing, but `if let` is much cleaner & safer for future refactoring (i.e what if you remove the check, but forget to remove the force unwrap).

Comment: @originaluser2 ok I get it